# video.js won't playback in Firefox, video/mp4" is not supported warning

Tags: 16.04, firefox, codecs, video-player, mp4

I'm new to Linux desktop environment.

I've just recently install a fresh **Ubuntu Desktop 16.04** and **Fedora 25** to learn.

I've installed `Firefox 51.0.1` on both Linux platforms as well as on a Windows 7 and OS X quadruple-boot environment.

I'm testing a video.js web page playback for mp4 videos, and got the following errors in the Developer Console.

`specified "type" attribute "video/mp4" is not supported`

**The video.js player on the web page won't play the video.**

This is happening to both Linux desktop Ubuntu and Fedora desktop.

However, with the same fresh installation of Firefox 51.0.1 on Windows 7 and OS X out of the box, and web page video.js playback of mp4 without any error/warning.

I also tested the `Chrome` browser in both Ubuntu and Fedora, and the installation will playback the same video.js web page with mp4 video without problem, no need for further configuration.

By the way, YouTube video playback is fine in all testing environments.

Is it something missing from the Firefox for Linux to begin with?

Since `Chrome` is capable of doing playback of the same web page, I assume the codecs should be in place.

Why is that Firefox in Linux is not working in this case, and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install using the following resolve the playback issue:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

However, I'
m just wondering why is that `Chrome` has everything working out of the box while Firefox needs to install additional 170MB of extra files?